# My "War Base" Editor isn't appearing in my War map!

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have started a war and today is preparation day. But, there is no option to edit my war base, and when I scout my enemy base, it shows that the war has ended.

What's the problem with that, and what is the solution?

Comment: If you want us to be able to help you, can you please translate your question to proper English ?

Comment: @Shunwoo That's not a post that's not spelt in English. That's just lazy typewriting from a user on an iPhone or some sort of mobile device!

Comment: @aytimothy I know, I have never said it wasn't in English, I just make a difference between this type of writing and proper English. I couldn't even understand the sense enough to be able to edit it myself ^^ .

Comment: @Shunwoo You need to make more spelling mistakes xD, or put up with peers who do that *a lot*.

Comment: @aytimothy Haha true, but I don't know if it is worth it to understand this type of writing ^^

Answer (score 0):

The reason for such is because the Clan war has already ended.

When the battle phase of clan wars finishes, the game automatically brings you straight to the results screen when you press the 'War' button in the interface for around 24 hours(?)*.
In there, you can view the attacks players have made and the damage on each of the bases.

*Not sure: But it might actually be until the next clan war is started.

---

It should look something like this:
[image]
Please note the **"War has ended"** in the center-top of the screen.